# renderPartial different model Yii several models working but not all of them

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial

i have a View that combines many models and I make a tab that each contains different models

this is my script at the view

```
<?php 
$this->widget(
        'booster.widgets.TbTabs',
        array(
            'type' => 'tabs',
            'tabs' => array(
                array(
                    'label'=>'Genset',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/genset', array('model'=>new genset), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'ATS',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/ats', array('model'=>new ats), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'UPS',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/ups', array('model'=>new ups), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'PLN',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/pln', array('model'=>new pln), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
            ),
        )
)
?>
```

at the final tab, which the label name is PLN doesn't work and return error like this

**CException
Property "pln.merk" is not defined.**

where there are something odd, pln is my model, and merk is not one of the columns from pln but from another model which is ats, i made this view file based on ats which has merk column, but this doesn't make sense when all of the view i do renderPartial like Genset, UPS, ATS works fine

only pln, and several other models throws an error message, like somehow they don't recognize the pln's model column but instead read the wrong column from ats model

Edit:

Basically the view is generated by CRUD, and this is the admin.php file where it contains CGridView

```
<?php
/* @var $this PlnController */
/* @var $model pln */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Plns'=>array('index'),
    'Manage',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List pln', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create pln', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#pln-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Manage Plns</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'pln-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'siteid',
        'capacity',
        'arus_r',
        'arus_s',
        'arus_t',
        /*
        'id_pelanggan',
        'jumlah_fasa',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

ATS.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this AtsController */
/* @var $model ats */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Ats'=>array('index'),
    'Manage',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List ats', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create ats', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#ats-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Dapot</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php 
$this->widget(
        'booster.widgets.TbTabs',
        array(
            'type' => 'tabs',
            'tabs' => array(
                array(
                    'label'=>'Genset',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/genset', array('model'=>new genset), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'ATS',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/ats', array('model'=>new ats), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'UPS',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/ups', array('model'=>new ups), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'Rectifier',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/rectifier', array('model'=>new rectifier), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'Baterai',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/baterai', array('model'=>new baterai), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'BBS',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/bbs', array('model'=>new bbs), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'Inverter',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/inverter', array('model'=>new inverter), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                array(
                    'label'=>'Trafo',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/trafo', array('model'=>new trafo), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),
                /*array(
                    'label'=>'PLN',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial('/ats/pln', array('model'=>new PLN), true ),
                    'active'=> false
                ),*/
            ),
        )
)
?>
```

Comment: would you post the `pln` view file (and might be `ats` view file)?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, so i use crud generator which creates the advanced search option code below, 
the 'model'=>$model overwrite the desired model, so i have to remove this code below if you use crud generator

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->
```

After that, i tried using the search function and it didn't work, so i added for each view to unset it's attributes

```
$model_x=new model_x('search');
$model_x->unsetAttributes();
if(isset($_GET['model_x']))
            $model_x->attributes=$_GET['model_x'];
```

now i'm stuck at the view,update,delete where it always uses ats as primary key identifier from the loadModel at the controller file